# How to correctly specify webdriver path with add_argument()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

But it did not use the webdriver that I am trying to specify and uses some different one. How to correctly specify path to webdriver in the code above?

So main point here is that I want to specify path to webdriver and also use it without sandbox. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# start the browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
# options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
# options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```